# Best Database Migration approach?

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am wondering what approach would be good to migrate your huge old data to new system database (Where table names and columns different from old system - need mapping tables and columns)?

1) Whether should it be database to database (means write scripts to extract data from old database and carefully map them and put it new one)? Above that write unit test to check the integerity.

(OR)

2) Should I use new system Model (using Java Persistence API) programme to extract data from old database then put it in objects (Hibernate or JPA Entity objects) and persist them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go with the first one.  This is what ETL tools were born for.

I would not recommend writing a Java program.  It'd be a great deal of effort to develop and test for a one-time use.  Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: True and, further to that, if the original datastore is big, no persistence tool would be able to compete on time taken with database migration tools.

Comment: Sorry, I do not mean to create whole new entites just for this purpose. Actually, we already have model for our new system so was thinking whether good idea to use new system model to populate with extract data from old system and persist? But, I think agree with DataNucleus that performance would be more higher in database to database approach.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently doing a data Migration from MySQL to Oracle and I found it best to follow this procedure.

1. Dump the old database structure and re-create it on the new DB system
2. Specify data map for the two systems
3. Import old data into new system using the old structure.
4. Create new DB structure.
5. Write SQL statements that will import your data from the old structure to the new structure.

This will minimise any data integrity issues and data mapping problems you might encounter.